AV1 Encoding Parameters Help - Reduce Variation in Quality from frame to frame
I'm encoding 16 bpc PNG sequences into various lossy video formats for archival purposes because the file sizes are so big. I'm only considering codecs which support 444 and at least 10 bit color. Right now the best I've found seem to be HEVC and AV1. In ffmpeg, they both support the yuv444p12le pixel format, which is great. However, I need help tuning the encode parameters to try and balance the the following as best as possible:

Maximize the minimum quality of any given frame of the animation
Keep the filesize relatively low.

Right now with AV1 I'm finding that the PSNR per frame tends to be a lot "spikier" than HEVC; and I don't know why. I attached an image as an example, where the blue line is the PSNR over each frame when encoding with AV1 while the pink is with HEVC.

The SSIM is similar, but not as bad:

The exact commands used to encode each are included below:
AV1:
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i "input%04d.png" -y -pix_fmt yuv444p12le -c:v libaom-av1 -crf 15 -b:v 500M -cpu-used 1 -row-mt 1 -tiles 2x2 output.mkv
HEVC:
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i "input%04d.png" -y -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 9 -pix_fmt yuv444p12le "output.mp4"
I don't like how there are big dips in the AV1 PSNR occurring repeatedly (the spikes downward in the blue line on the PSNR plot), since it means there are big differences from one frame to the next, even if the overall average PSNR level is pretty high. I'd prefer to make it smoother if possible.
It doesn't seem to be an issue with HEVC.
Do you have suggestions for changes I can make to my AV1 encoding command which will prevent those spikes? If so, can you also explain why those changes will help?
